# Gradle DSL method not found: 'buildToolsVersion()'

Tags: android, facebook

I am new in Android-Studio

In that I have imported facebook and one other third party sdk

but I am getting following error

```
Error:(16, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'buildToolsVersion()'
Possible causes:The project 'EmojiShare' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file, The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin
```

[image]

my build.gradle file's code is below

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

in app/build.gradle the code is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "emoji.drcsystems.com.emojishare"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':EmojiconApp')

}
```

Comment: Please post your `build.gradle` files. One is at the top level of your project; one is in the `app` module.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare thank you so much for replying me I have updated my question just check it out

Comment: @SiddhpuraAmit Please also post the other one described by @CommonsWare (located in the `app` module).

Comment: @CommonsWare if I have removed facebook and again import then I am getting following errror Error:(17, 0) Could not find property 'ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION' on project ':facebooklib'.

Comment: @PattaFeuFeu just read above comments

Comment: What you have seems fine, though I would not use `23.0.0 rc2` with version `1.2.3` of the plugin. Use `22.0.1` or older.